# Jenkins Matrix build: how to build once and publish that binary to slaves?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins Matrix build that splits my Android tests across 5 nodes in parallel.  At the moment each of those 5 nodes has to build my Android binary, which takes a couple of minutes (which means I'm paying for 6x the number of VMs I need for this build step).

Does anybody know how I could build my binary once and publish the resulting artifact to the slaves in the Matrix build?

I'm pretty sure I could achieve this by using a Jenkins "MultiJob Project", but that has the disadvantage that I need to configure the master and slave jobs completely separately.

Does anybody have any better ideas?

Even better, could I have the Android build running on the master while the emulators are starting on all the slaves?!  That would be amazing...

Comment: Regarding having the emulators start up while the APK gets built, I don't know — perhaps the relatively new Workflow Plugin for Jenkins could be used to build such a workflow, but possibly the Android Emulator plugin would have to be made compatible. But (at least if you're using x86 system image emulators, or perhaps snapshots) starting the emulators should be pretty quick anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split things into two jobs: one regular (freestyle) job that builds the app, archives the APK upon success, and triggers a downstream build of your test (matrix) job.

The matrix job would use the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to pull the just-compiled APK into the workspace of each matrix variation. Regardless of where the build  ran, or where the test builds are running, the APK will be copied to the right machine(s) automatically.

You could also save money by running more than one emulator per (virtual) machine, as it shouldn't generally be necessary to keep emulators isolated.